# How to merge two cells ONLY IF they are not the same?

Tags: excel-2010

I understand cells can be merged with something the like the following:

```
=B2&", "&C2
```

This works great for cells in column B that are different than cells in column C.

However, if the cells are the same, I would like to output only the contents of cells in column B.

Is this doable in Excel 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using an `If` formula:

`=If(B2=C2,B2,B2&", "&C2)`